# Indexing to check whether a very large table contains an exact string in a certain column

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016

I have a very large SQL table (~500 million rows)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDefinition]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [TeamId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want to insert new records in the table but first I need to make sure the record doesn't already exist.

I essentially build a table with the values (`@TestDefinitionInput` - a TVP) I want to insert and then I pass it into a stored procedure.

```
WITH W AS 
(
   SELECT [Name], TeamId
   FROM @TestDefinitionInput
),
X AS 
(
   SELECT W.* 
   FROM W
   LEFT JOIN TestDefinition td ON td.TeamId = W.TeamId AND td.[Name] = W.[Name] 
   WHERE td.Id IS NULL
)
INSERT INTO TestDefinition ([Name], [TeamId]) 
   SELECT [Name], [TeamId]
   FROM X;
```

My problem is that this is really slooow with 500 million rows. I really am not very proficient at SQL and am wondering how I should, if I should, index `dbo.[TestDefinition]` to make this as fast as possible.

Comment: TeamId is unique in the Team table (it's its primary key) but a team can have many test definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of possibilities:

You could consider changing your primary key to:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TeamId ASC, [Id] ASC)
```

At the expense of widening the clustered index attached to the primary key, you won't burn your range searching index on the Identity column. This would require periodic defraging

The other (**probably preferred**) option is to create a non clustered index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TestDefinition_TeamId_Name 
    ON dbo.TestDefinition(TeamId, Name)
```

[Note: no need to explicitly INCLUDE `Id` as it's the clustering key, and that is added to every non-clustered index.]

I would also consider placing the incoming TVP parameter values into a temporary table rather than a table variable, and join to that table (even creating a corresponding index on it). Table vars are notorious for poor cardinality estimates.

I would also consider adding the index with page compression (and the table if you can)

```
.... with (data_compression = page);
```

[Data compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression) is not available in every edition of SQL Server. SQL Server 2016 onwards, it's in Standard edition.

The other thing you should consider is to perform the inserts in batches of say 50K or 100K at a time, with a short sleep in-between. This can prevent massive log file growth and contention, and allow other processes to have a chance to access the table.

Comment: Is doing both of the options you mentioned counter productive?

Comment: I suspect the hassle will outweigh the benefit. Go with second option with compression is my feeling.

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- any good resource tips to learn about proper index tuning? I find it overwhelming.

Comment: Pluralsight have a few courses. RedGate have some free materials. Everything by Kimberly Tripp and Paul Randal. Also Brent Ozar

Comment: 2nd option and tvp into temp table, fantastic improvement!